# PHP: Prepared Statements cannot escape from single quotes

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, escaping, prepared-statement

I'm inserting value to MySql for sign up. Because of the 'single quotes' problem, i worked with prepared statements. Normally i was using addslashes but it doesnt work with all sql query, works only specific row. Let me explain :

It's simple sign up activity.

Android side of my code :

```
 final String email=_email.getText().toString();
        final String password=_password.getText().toString();

        final String sqlcode ="Insert into login (email,password) VALUES ('"+email+"','"+password+"')";
        final String sqllogin="SELECT email FROM login WHERE email= '"+email+"'";

@Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String,String> params=new HashMap<>();
                params.put("sqllogin",sqllogin);
                params.put(getString(R.string.sqlcode),sqlcode);
                return params;
            }
```

PHP side of my code :

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] =='POST'){

    $sqllogin = $_POST["sqllogin"];
    $sqlcode= $_POST["sqlcode"];

    require_once 'connect.php';

    mysqli_query($conn,"SET NAMES 'utf8'");

    $stmtcheck = $conn->prepare($sqllogin);
    $stmtcheck->execute();
    $stmtcheck->store_result();

      if ( $stmtcheck->num_rows >0) { // if email exists
      $result["message"] = "duplicate";

        echo json_encode($result);
        mysqli_close($conn);
        $stmtcheck->close();
      }
      else //if email !exists create one
      { 
        $stmtcheck->close();
        $stmtadd = $conn->prepare($sqlcode);

        if ($stmtadd->execute()) { 
            // it worked
            $result["message"] = "success";
            echo json_encode($result);
            mysqli_close($conn);
            $stmtadd->close();
         } else {
            // it didn't
            $result["message"] = "error";
            echo json_encode($result);
            mysqli_close($conn);
            $stmtadd->close();
         }
   }
}

?>
```

I work with prepared statements completely as you see. But i dont understand why single quotes not inserting to the database.
The more strange thing is : I can insert double quotes.

Comment: I can't see any prepared Statement. Do not sent SQL queries from android to the backend

Comment: as i know $stmt is prepared statement. But i guess, i know wrong

Comment: Your Android code does not use prepared statements and is subject to SQL injection attacks, depending on the emall and password supplied.
This is a major security risk.
It also seems as if your passwords are being kept as plain text, which is another major security risk.

Comment: I need to use sql queries in android. Because when i want to send one parameter i'm using item.phpand i'm using this almost 50 times.I can't create 50 different php files. So I'm sending queries from android.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not using prepared statements! Your app is a massive security disaster waiting to happen

You are generating an SQL string in your android app and posting that to the web application. The web application does call `$conn->prepare` but it's using a complete SQL statement that has been built with string munging somewhere else. It does not have any place holders for parameter binding.

In short what you are doing is executing sql commands that a client gives you on trust.

Comment: So, do you have any idea " why double quotes working and single is not" ? Normally both wasn't working.

Comment: Are you still considering fixing the issue rather than just sending a request with the email + password?

Comment: I sent email and password to the php. And i used addslashes. Now its working

Comment: FYI, you don't need to use addslashes if you use [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) correctly

Comment: It worked perfectly. Now i use this bind_param instead of addslashes after this. I can even combine this params with all of my sql queries like here ( sqlcode)

Comment: Sorry i had to step away after typing this answer. Glad that it's sorted out now